# Block matrix composed of square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, be $n\times n$ matrices.

a) Show that the block matrix $\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}$ has rank at least as large as the rank of $A$.

b) Show that the matrices $\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}A+B & B\\
B & B
\end{bmatrix}$ are equivalent.

c) Show that the $rank(A+B)\leq rank(A)+rank(B)$.

Does anybody have an idea to prove above statements?

Comment: Do you know that *rank* of a matrix can be defined as the dimension of its row space (equiv. dimension of its column space)?

Comment: @hardmath yeah, how would you apply it to the statement?

Comment: Seems like homework questions!

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani It is. I just need a way to start the proof

Comment: Well then, start with the definition of rank for a)

Comment: So, Mark, can you compare the rank of the block matrix to the rank of upper rows $[A \; B]$, using the definition we discussed?

Comment: so the rank is the dimension of the image of the block matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints

1. For the first one, Rank of any matrix is equal to the number of independent non-zero rows that a matrix can have.
2. For the second one, take the 2nd matrix and try row reductions. Row reduced forms of a matrix are equivalent to the original matrix.
3. I'm not sure of a rigorous way but you can prove that $(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{}\mathbf{Ax}+\mathbf{Bx}$ can span the space at most the space spanned by $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}$ together by considering tall matrices. For a wide matrix the equality can never be attained and for square matrix it's obvious.

Comment: From $(A+B)x = Ax + Bx$ we see that the column space of $A+B$ is contained in the span of the column space of $A$ and the column space of $B$.

Comment: For b) or part 2, (block) row reduction alone does not achieve a tranformation of the second matrix into the first; column operations are also needed.